# Collect data through google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics-api

I searched the web for a long time but I didn't find an answer for my question. Maybe it's general not possible what I try to do or I'm searching with the wrong keywords. If an anonymous user go to my website, google analytics creates the _ga cookie to identify this user later. This cookie holds an identifier. I want to use this identifier to collect more information about the user through the google analytics API. Maybe it's possible thorugh  filters of the google analytics api?

Comment: The information available via the Google Analytics API is the same information available in the GA website.  If the information you are looking for isn't already in the GA website then you aren't going to find it in the API.

Comment: I think the approach you may need to use is custom variables.  [Check out this article](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/custom-variables-segmentation); the **Visitor Level Custom Variable** section.